# Scrapy to follow links in a specific div

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to follow related links but I am not having any success.  I am getting "Crawled 0 pages" with my scrapy script (brand new to scrapy).

I am trying to crawl a series of pages that looks has a section like this:

```
<div id="index">
<h2>Find Listings </h2>
<div class="group">
  <h3>A</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/STATE-City/Segment-number-one">Segment-number-one</a></li>
      <li><a href="/STATE-City/Segment-number-two">Segment-number-two</a></li>
      <li><a href="/STATE-City/Segment-number-three">Segment-number-three</a></li>
```

And so on...

When following the links, the next level has data that I want to parse out some data.  When I parse the page directly, it pulls the data I want.  However, I am not getting the script to follow each of the links above.

My current script:

```
    class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "domain"
        allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
        start_urls = ['http://URL/STATE-City1', 
                      'http://URL/STATE-City2']      
        rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/STATE-\w+/*?$"), callback='parse_contents'),)        

        def parse_contents(self, response):
            for bus in response.css('div.resultWrapper'):
                yield {        
                    'field1': bus.css('div.resultInner a::text').extract_first(),
                    'field2': bus.css('p.field2::text').extract_first(),
                    'field3': bus.css('span.field3::text').extract_first(),
                    'field4': bus.css('span.field4::text').extract(),
                    'field5' : bus.css('span.field5::text').extract(),
                }
```

Thanks for any help.

BCBB

Comment: Did you miss a dot there? `/STATE-\w+/*?$` vs `/STATE-\w+/.*?$`?

Comment: The link does not have a file extension.  The actual path to the page I want to parse is:  http : // URL/STATE-City1/Segment-number-one/     And the cities are not City1 (no numbers).

Comment: Dot is not a file extension delimiter here, `.` in a regular expression would mean any character making a wildcard `.*?` pattern meaning "any character any number of times in a non-greedy manner".

Comment: Haha...  Yeah totally misread your comment.  I think my eyes corrected for it...  Definitely the problem.  I love it when you are looking for something complex so you look past the obvious.  Thanks for your help!